# Javascript splitting an object in QT

Tags: javascript, facebook, qt

I'm trying to split a URL to capture a token from the end.

It returns an error: Property 'split' of object https://.. is not a function.
I am trying to get the access token for a Facebook login at the end of a URL, does the code url need to be converted to a string, is it not a function because I am trying to split an object?

```
function extractToken(url)
{
    var str = url
    var res = str.split("code");
    var accessToken = res[1]
    console.log(accessToken)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `url` is a string?

Comment: It's passed from QML as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it to work now, it seems that by placing a string in front of the url it meant that there was no longer a reference error. Here's what I did.

```
onUrlChanged: {
    console.log(url);
    extractToken("" + url);
}
```